# trouble validating page if array contain 100+ values

Tags: php, sql, arrays, validation

I am trying to run a function from a php page.  Within this function I pass 4 different arrays.  If one of the arrays  contain 100 or more values or if the combination of the 4 arrays total to 100+ nothing happens post submit.  No validation, no errors, no time out.  Page remains the same without action.  When I have less than a 100 values in that array, the function runs as expected’.  Has anyone experienced something like this?

Comment: you may have hit your memory limit http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php ? are you able to check/increase it?

Comment: Maybe `max_input_vars` but if no error messages in logs probably memory as Dave suggested.

Comment: I've increased the memory limit to 1024 M from 128 M.  No change with results and running php 5.3.3.

Comment: There is no max_input_vars set.

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem was not being able to pass over 1000 post variables.  I assumed that there was no limitation, since max_input_vars was not listed in the php.ini file.  Later, I added max_input_vars = 5000 to the ini file and it is working properly.